# Errors in Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, debugging, machine-learning

*This is my code:*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv")

df.head()
```

*And the errors occur:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python/machine learning/regression.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv",engine = 'python')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 452, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 946, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1189, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2382, in __init__
    f, handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 496, in get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, errors="replace", newline="")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FuelConsumption.csv'
```

I'm sure that I've downloaded the csv but it still doesn't work
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File path is the main argument of the read_csv method. You should specify the path of the csv file, if both python file and csv file are not in the same directory, you can use relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of your workspaces and your CSV file are in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks, but try to `comment` one-line answers

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put your file.csv and .py in the same folder.